# Copy range of row using two dropdown list as start time and end time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, validation

I have list of data that fetched from SQL at defined time range:

[image: Pivot Data Fetched form SQL]

At that image I also already make dropdown list named `Start time` and `End time`.

The question is: how can I make a macro that the output is copying entire row with range of `Start time` and `End time` from the dropdown list?

I also already try with chat GPT but the result is blank without error message, I tried various configuration but no luck, btw I'm new to the macro VBA.

Here is the code from chatGPT (I already modified it):

```
Sub CopyRowsBasedOnDropdowns()
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim Dropdown1 As String
Dim Dropdown2 As String
Dim Cell As Range

' Set the source and target sheets
Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PivotSF") ' Change "SourceSheet" to your source sheet name
Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filteredtiming") ' Change "TargetSheet" to your target sheet name

' Get the selected values from the dropdowns
Dropdown1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PivotSF").Range("I3").Value ' Change "DropdownSheet" and "A1" to your dropdown cell
Dropdown2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PivotSF").Range("K3").Value ' Change "DropdownSheet" and "A2" to your second dropdown cell

' Define the range to copy
Set CopyRange = SourceSheet.Range("A2:F" & SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) ' Change "A" and the range as needed

' Clear previous data in the target sheet
TargetSheet.Cells.Clear

' Loop through the source sheet and copy rows that match the dropdown criteria
For Each Cell In CopyRange
    If Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Dropdown1 And Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Dropdown2 Then ' Change the offset and criteria as needed
        LastRow = TargetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cell.EntireRow.Copy TargetSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1)
    End If
Next Cell
```

End Sub

Comment: In the last section of the macro the if statement is using `=`. I'm sure one needs to be changed to `>` and the other to `<`. I am assuming everything else in the macro is working...